# UITableView not loaded

Tags: cocoa-touch

i've followed a tutorial in wich you were Guided trough the development of a little, actual simple XML Application on iPhone.

I followed the Tutorial and run into one problem: The UITableView is empty, alltough the NSMutabelArray is not empty. The curious thing is, that i am not able to find diferences in the code of the Tutorial and my programmed code.

I tried different suggestions and ideas from [UITableView gives empty table, does not load data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597576/uitableview-gives-empty-table-does-not-load-data-solved), but either the iPhone screen turned Black or nothing was changed.

So i put both Projects (the downloaded Tutorial and my own Project) at my FTP server for you ftp://homes.dnsalias.com
If i missed information that is necessary or helpful please tell me. I hope someone, is willing to explain my mistake.

Thank you a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have had some basic Problems with UINavigationControllers and TableViews.
For those who found this Thread on google or something, here is a, for me helpfull, youtube link: [link text](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw&feature=related)